# Get cost or bandwidth contributed by a file in total AWS bill

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser-cache, cache-control

I am using AWS S3 for serving assets to my website, now even though I have added cache-control metadata header to all my assets my daily overall bandwidth usage almost got doubled in past month.
I am sure that traffic on my website has not increased dramatically to account for increase in S3's bandwidth usage.

Is there a way to find out how much a file is contributing to the total bill in terms of bandwidth or cost ?

I am routing all my traffic through cloudfare so it should be protected against DDoS attack.

I expect the bandwidth of my S3 bucket to reduce or to get some valid reason which explains why bandwidth almost doubled when there's no increase in daily traffic.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) on your content bucket. Once you do this, all bucket accesses will be written to logfiles that are stored in a (different) S3 bucket.

You can analyze these logfiles with a custom program (you'll find examples on the web) or [AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html), which lets you write SQL queries against structured data.

I would focus on the remote IP address of the requestor, to understand what proportion of requests are served via CloudFlare versus people going directly to your bucket.

If you find that CloudFlare *is* constantly reloading content from the bucket, you'll need to give some thought to cache-control headers, either as metadata on the object in S3, or in your CloudFlare configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html

To enable CloudTrail data events logging for objects in an S3 bucket:

Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.

In the Bucket name list, choose the name of the bucket that you want.

Choose Properties.

Choose Object-level logging.

Choose an existing CloudTrail trail in the drop-down menu. The trail you select must be in the same AWS Region as your bucket, so the drop-down list contains only trails that are in the same Region as the bucket or trails that were created for all Regions.

If you need to create a trail, choose the CloudTrail console link to go to the CloudTrail console. For information about how to create trails in the CloudTrail console, see Creating a Trail with the Console in the AWS CloudTrail User Guide.

Under Events, select Read to specify that you want CloudTrail to log Amazon S3 read APIs such as GetObject. Select Write to log Amazon S3 write APIs such as PutObject. Select both Read and Write to log both read and write object APIs. For a list of supported data events that CloudTrail logs for Amazon S3 objects, see Amazon S3 Object-Level Actions Tracked by CloudTrail Logging in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

Choose Create to enable object-level logging for the bucket.

To disable object-level logging for the bucket, you must go to the CloudTrail console and remove the bucket name from the trail's Data events.